# Use CNN for regression task in Keras

Tags: deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I want to use CNN for regression problem (Keras, TF backend). It's possible by simply change last layer (Dense) activations to linear and use euclidean distance as loss function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you mean change the last activation to linear is actually just no activation, if you set the activation = None, then the last layer will be a linear layer. see keras dense layer:

```
keras.layers.Dense(units, activation=None, use_bias=True, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros', kernel_regularizer=None, bias_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None, kernel_constraint=None, bias_constraint=None)
```

And the euclidean distance as loss function is actually same as mean_squared_error. euclidean distance is just sqrt(mean_squared_error), so it is same.

Comment: So it's correct use euclidian distance as loss and mean squared error as metrics? It's actually that I'm using.

Comment: you may should use the mean_squared_error as loss, because tensorflow use loss to do bp. And it is already implement, you could also use the mean_squared_error as metrics or euclidian distance, because the metrics is just used for you to judge the model performance and loss would be used to train model.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you need to use a linear output, you can also normalize the outputs and use a sigmoid activation. Then you use a mean squared error loss.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "linear output"? I use Dense layer with linear activation as last layer and Euclidean Distance in model.compile as loss function. This is what you mean?

Comment: Yes, its the same.